# Requests keeping my IP address whereas I'm using Tor

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-proxy

when I do python requests I notice that this is my actual IP address that get sent to the requests whereas I've set a new one using Tor.
Here is my code:

```
from torrequest import TorRequest

tr = TorRequest(proxy_port=9050, ctrl_port=9051, password=r"mypassword")
response = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/plain')
proxies = {'http': "socks5://"+response.text+":9050"}

page_response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?&q=Apple', timeout=60, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': random.choice(user_agents)}, proxies=proxies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
```

However, google realises that it is still my IP address and not the Tor generated one.
How come?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that Google can get your actual IP while you are using a proxy? Chances are the proxy you are using could be blocked by Google or proxy get timeout during first connect.

To understand these possible cause you can code like this ->

```
from torrequest import TorRequest

tr = TorRequest(proxy_port=9050, ctrl_port=9051, password=r"mypassword")
response = tr.get('http://ipecho.net/plain')
proxies = {'http': "socks5://"+response.text+":9050"}

# Using this check, you will know weather your proxies are working or not.
# if proxy for request and current ip are same than proxy is working
try:
    print "The proxy for request is {0}".format(response.text)
    proxy_check = requests.get('http://icanhazip.com', timeout=60, proxies=proxies)
    print "Proxy is {0}".format(proxy_check)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e

# we should catch request exception to check any exception raise from requests like 
# timeout
try:
    page_response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?&q=Apple', timeout=60, verify=False, headers={'User-Agent': random.choice(user_agents)}, proxies=proxies)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, 'html.parser')
```

Now you can know which IP you are using to access Google. If proxy is good then chances are Google has already blocked that proxy.

Comment: I've pasted your code but when google blocks me, it states my real IP address. So Still the same error...

Comment: Which IP did this check return ```proxy_check = requests.get('http://icanhazip.com', timeout=60, proxies=proxies)``` . If this print your real ip than proxy is not working. If  it print your proxy ip than google has banned that proxy you are using.